# How to design the universal class?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to build universal form. But I do not know how to do it.

Now I have

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InheritanceDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IPresenter _presenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenter = new Presenters(this);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.Retrive();
        }
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class Presenter : IPresenter
{
    private readonly IView _view;

    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }
}
```

I have tried something like this, but it not work.

```
public partial class Form1<T> : Form
{
    private T _presenter;

    public Form1(T presenter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._presenter = presenter;
    }
```

How to create a base class so that each derived class could define its own Presenter. In fact I will not use class Form1. I will use only derived classes.

Maybe I should use some kind of pattern?

Comment: "but it not work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @dotctor please check update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **virtual** in Base class and **override** in derived class to get intended behaviour.

**EDIT 1:**

Looking at your question again with modified comments, I believe you do not need any derived classes rather the generic class will itself suffice. So you define something like following. Additionally, you may put a constraint on the generic Type to be class.

```
public partial class Form1<T> : Form Where T : Class
{
    private T _presenter;

    public Form1(T presenter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._presenter = presenter;
    }
}
```

If you have specific reason for using Derived class, please specify.

Comment: Can you give an example? In fact I will not use class Form1. I will use only derived classes.

Comment: I've updated the post. Actually Presenter has a constructor that takes a parameter. Through this parameter it is passed a reference to an instance of the class that is. How do I create an instance of your example, meet these requirements?